# jQuery/bootstrap show datepicker when button is clicked and assign value to variable without input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Quite new to jQuery so please bear with me...

I would like to show the datepicker when I click a button. The datepicker should appear as a popup and assign the selected date to a variable.

My attempt so far

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='snapshot_btn()'>
  Snapshot 
</button><input type="hidden" id="button_snapshot" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

and in the `main.js`

```
function snapshot_btn() {
    $("#button_snapshot").datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        onSelect: function () {
            var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            alert(dateObject);
        }
    });    
}
```

but the datepicker does not show when I click the button.

It shows normally on other input boxes.

Comment: add jquery and then add jquery ui , code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rveodv?editors=1010

Comment: which package of `jquery datapicker` that you use? I am not sure it is JqueryUI one

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
Since in your original question you didn't say that it was bootstrap datepicker, not jQuery datepicker, I made this answer using jQuery datepicker.

You need to add the two libraries (jquery and then jquery UI, check the snippet to get the links), after that, 
just use the code below and in the `onSelect` function, get the date as parameter, it already contains the selection.

I made a slight change, removing the `input type='hidden'`, and adding an empty `div`, that way the calendar will appear inline.

My example also makes the calendar disappear and reappear on click, take a look.

```js
function snapshot_btn() {
  var btnOpenCalendar = $("#btnOpenCalendar");
  
  if (btnOpenCalendar.hasClass('calendar-open')){
    btnOpenCalendar.removeClass("calendar-open");
    $("#button_snapshot").datepicker("destroy");
    
  }else{
    btnOpenCalendar.addClass("calendar-open");
    $("#button_snapshot").datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        onSelect: function (date) {
            alert(date);
        }
    });  

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button type="button" id='btnOpenCalendar' class="btn btn-primary" onclick='snapshot_btn()'>
  Snapshot 
</button>
<div id="button_snapshot"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With bootstrap-datepicker, add `autoHide:true` inside datepicker() and `.datepicker("show");` right after. When use click the button, the modal will show up, and hide when you click outside

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='snapshot_btn()'>Snapshot </button>
<input type="hidden" id="button_snapshot" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
function snapshot_btn() {
    $("#button_snapshot").datepicker({
        autoHide:true,
        showOn: 'both',
        onSelect: function () {
            var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            alert(dateObject);
        }
    });  
    $("#button_snapshot").datepicker("show");
}
```